# cannot connect ssh as root

Tags: server, ssh, ftp, sftp

Hello I realy dont have a lot of knowledge about servers/ftp etc so i'm sorry if i don't sound undertandable juste tell me how to tell you more acurate info..
I have followed a tutorial to make my ftp use sftp here is the link :
https://memo-linux.com/mettre-en-place-un-serveur-sftp-sous-debian-8/
the link is not in english but this is what i did :

```
apt install openssh-server
```

then i opened /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and i changed Port 22 to Port 666
also i added this at the end of the file :

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
         Match group sftp
         ChrootDirectory /home/%u
         X11Forwarding no
         AllowTcpForwarding no
```

then i have written all these commands in the terminal :

```
addgroup sftp
mkdir -p /home/fred
useradd -s /bin/false -d /home/fred -g sftp fred
passwd fred
chown root:root /home/fred/
chmod -R 770 /home/fred/
usermod -d / fred
```

then the tutorial asked to activate the sftp this way :

```
systemctl restart ssh
```

But I got this error :

```
Job for ssh.service failed. See 'systemctl status ssh.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Then i got logged out so I tried to reconnect with theses ways but no one worked :

```
sftp fred@IPofServer
```

got : ssh: connect to host IPofServer port 22: Connection refused

```
sftp fred@IPofServer:666
```

got : ssh: connect to host IPofServer port 22: Connection refused

```
ssh fred@IPofServer
```

got : ssh: connect to host IPofServer port 22: Connection refused

```
ssh root@IPofServer
```

got : ssh: connect to host IPofServer port 22: Connection refused

```
ssh root@IPofServer -p 666
```

ssh: connect to host IPofServer port 666: Resource temporarily unavailable

```
sftp -oPort=666 root@IPofServer
```

ssh: connect to host IPofServer port 666: Resource temporarily unavailable

Now I have changed the file using Webmin (I dont know why he can connect to the server but he did..)
i changed back 666 to 22 and removed the piece of code from the end of the file

but still :

```
ssh root@IPofServer
```

ssh: connect to host IPofServer port 22: Connection refused

If you need more info please tell me

Comment: Your ssh server is not running, that's why you cannot connect. You made some mistake in sshd_config file. Your error message says to check the output of 'systemctl status ssh.service' and 'journalctl -xn' commands. What do they show?

Comment: but i can't run any command now because I can't connect.. how am i supposed to check the output ?

Comment: Do you have any other way to access the machine? Can you physically access it and login?

Comment: No.. only webmin allows me to see and edit files but the terminal doent allow me for exemple :

`[root@save ~]# ls 
Error opening terminal: unknown.`

Comment: I see now that you have reverted your config file back to previous state. So you only need a way to start your ssh server again. Can you do it using webmin?

Comment: it doesnt let me use the terminal, is there another way to start it ?
only the filemanager is working

Comment: It seems that there is some way to run commands through webmin, as you have already quoted above the error message from ```ls``` command. So try to run ```systemctl start ssh```

Comment: raj thanks a lot for your help, there was a button in a sub menu in web min to activate it manually, it helped me a lot to know that the ssh was off thanks !

Comment: Please describe what you exactly did, and add as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Webmin I just restarted the SSH server manualy this way :
Webmin -> Servers -> SSH Server -> Start button